# Resizing Boot Disk isn't taking effect

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, partition

I have a VM Ubuntu 20.10 instance on GCP. It initially had 40 GB Boot disk space which got full and to increase it I had followed google official tutorials and it's showing on console that it has resized to 100 GB but when I SSH into instance it shows the disk is still 40 GB. Attached are some screenshots for reference

[SSH Command to check disk Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHnB5.png)

[VM Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBcwL.png)

[Disk Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAC4M.png)

I had restarted Instace several times.

Comment: I wrote an article on how the resize works. This might help you debug what is going wrong. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-debian-9-resize-root-file-system/

Comment: Did you forget to increase *partition* and *file system* size inside the VM after the disk was enlarged? Read this: https://serverfault.com/questions/994448 . (Probably, your question could be considered a duplicate of that one.)

Comment: Also, if it's GPT, you might need to move the backup GPT to the new end before adding / extending partition.