# How to resize partition to maximum size on Debian 8?

Tags: centos, partition, disk-volume

My question is how to resize partition on Debian 8 without losing any data?
I have 90 GB partition but my disk has 150 GB space on VPS server, so 50 GB is free and I want to add this 50 GB without losing any data, this is how it presents:

[image: 2]

I've tried using **resize2fs** command but this didn't helped me because it shows me an error :

> Filesystem is already n blocks long. Nothing to do!

I've already extended a partition on Debian 11 with resize2fs and everything was fine, here I don't know why but It doesn't want to work.

EDIT

[image]

Comment: Use a partition manager, like fdisk or parted, print out the current partition table in Bytes, delete the partition which you want to increase, create a new partition with exact same values as the deleted one, but the end Byte is this time bigger, save changes to partition and exit your partition manager. Use resize2fs again. **PS create a backup of your original partition table before going to delete anything. PPS if you create the new partition wrongly, you'll probably lose data. PPPS use a newer Debian version.**

Comment: PS also deactivate SWAP partition first and delete SWAP partition also.

Comment: You have to (1) resize partition, which is requires a free space right next to the vda1 (where your swap is located on the disk?), and must be carried while *unmount* for most of the filesystem types (is yours an ext*?). Only then, you have to (2) resize the filesystem.

Comment: please provide the output of `lsblk --fs`

Comment: @Brahim vda1 is ext4

Comment: We see two partitions, but it is unclear how it's laid out on disk. Numbers don't always correspond to real on-disk order, but to order of entries in the partition table. For instance. it is possible to make vda2 to be located ahead of vda1 on disk. To be sure, show `fdisk -l /dev/vda`. (Actually I need that to know if you should do anything with that swap partition or not.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your disk layout, you have to

(0) move away the swap partition to leave space for extending `vda1`; partition space must be contiguous. for this purpose:

- disable swap, with `swapoff /dev/vda2` (`/dev/vda2` is your swap device file. Always check my arguments)
- remove swap partition using `parted /dev/vda rm partno` where *partno* is the swap partition number according to `parted /dev/vda`, (it should 2 ?)
- recreate the swap partition at the end of the disk, with `/dev/parted /dev/vda mkpart -4G -1s`. Negative numbers here are references from the end of the disk, meaning that the partition spans the *last* 4GiB of the disk (`-1s` means the partition ends at the last sector of disk, which is impossible as this will overwrite the secondary GPT header, so `parted` will modify the exact start/end and alignment of the partition (you'll be prompted). The partition will be created with the same number 2. So the device file will be named `/dev/vda2`. You have to check it.
- re-enable the swap, with `mkswap /dev/vda2` then `swapon /dev/vda2`
- update the line having `RESUME=` in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` if any. This line specifies the partition used for hibernation, and it is identified either with `UUID=...` or `LABEL=...`. You can find the swap partition UUID or label using `blkid`
- update the line describing the swap partition in the fs table `/etc/fstab`. Just update UUID, label or partition number (depending on how the swap partition is designated in the file)

Once swap is moved away, you have to

(1) resize your root partition, which now has free space next to it. You can use command `growpart` (from package `cloud-utils`) which makes a partition use all the available space. If you cannot get this package on your system, you can do it manually with the subcommand `resizepart` of `parted`, telling only partition number (1?) and the END position (in blocks). Refer to `parted /dev/vda` to get expected END position. `parted` will prevent you from accidentally overwrite the swap.

(2) resize the filesystem (ext4 can be grown online, no need to unmount it) using `resize2fs /dev/vda1`

These steps will solve your issue, normally with no dataloss. However it is recommended to backup the most important data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove swap partition, extend the data partition and re-create the swap if you need it.

If you have enough free memory (swap is not used much), you may do this without interruption the service. Begin with: `swapoff /dev/vda2`, to release the swap. If you unable to do that (not enough memory), you'll need to stop memory-consuming services until you can disable swap.

After successfull swapoff, run `fdisk /dev/vda` and remove the second partition.

Now decide how much swap do you need and calculate where should it begin. For instance, if you want to have exactly 8 GiB (16777216 sectors) swap as you have now, and you have exactly 150 GiB (314572800 sectors) disk, your swap should begin at sector 314572800-16777216 = 297795584. So create new vda2 partition of type 82 (Linux swap), which begins on this sector and the 314572799 (it should suggest this value by itself). **Don't use my numbers blindly, calculate them yourself, because I made an assumption about the disk size — you somewhat hide parts of information that could make this calculation exact.** (And in the future don't post screenshots of the console, but just copy and paste it as text, that's much better. And don't omit such information as disk partitioning, better copy complete output; it couldn't be used to identify you or to do any harm, but makes life easier.)

When you recreated swap partition at the end of the drive, you may extend your first partition. It is described in detail in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/994448/extend-linux-partition-size-without-losing-any-data-techniques/994465#994465), so I just outline it here and you can always refer there for the details.

Notice your `vda1` begins at sector 2048. This is very important!

1. Remove the first partition. Yes, do it. Yes, on the running system. Nothing will happen and nothing will be lost.
2. Create new partition 1, it should begin at exact sector 2048 and end at or past the current last sector, 188745727. Make sure your new partition begins at 2048 and is not any smaller that it was! Also notice, it may detect a file system signature and suggest to wipe it. **Don't wipe**.
3. Commit changes to disk (`w`), fdisk should exit and say that partition table is written, but kernel still uses old partition table. Use `kpartx` or `partprobe` to reload it, as it suggests. Or disable swap in `/etc/fstab` and reboot (you need to disable it for it to not halt boot due to missing swap signature).
4. At this point your `lsblk` should already show new partition size. You may extend the file system with `resize2fs /dev/vda1`. As for swap, create new swap structure with `mkswap /dev/vda2` and, if `/etc/fstab` refers to swap using UUID, update it with new value that mkswap had printed to you.

Comment: why should partition 1 be removed? is not this the root partition!!

Comment: Remove and then create a partition which begins at the same sector is exactly same thing as "resizing" a partition. Essentially it just changes some numbers in the partition table record. If you think `growpart` is doing something else, you don't understand what is going on.

Comment: No I do not. But I think that growing (`growpart`) or resizing (`parted resizepart`) are less prone to user errors, and easier.

Comment: But why should I install additional software which I would almost never use, when there is already a software which could do the job? Yes, some tools may look like less error prone, but also give less control. Also, why do you still refer to the same operation using different terms, as if those tools do something other than just updating same numbers in partition table in the same way?

Comment: Every thing comes at a cost, so one may accept to install additional software to avoid routine or focus consuming tasks. Note that `parted` provides `resizepart` subcommand to fulfill this common use case, `growpart` is a standalone alternative. One would fallback to `fdisk` for uncommon partition manipulation scenario.